# How to speed down two-fingers trackpad scrolling?

Tags: touchpad, trackpad

I move the arrow of touchpad speed bar to the left. Also, I tweak dconf editor's touchpad setting motion-acceleration, motion-threshold, etc.. and it didn't work. After all, if I change scroll-method from two-finger-scrolling to edge-scrolling, it didn't change at all, also set touchpad-enable to off, and it didn't change too. Those are answers posted on askubuntu. So what are these setting? Is it any meaningful functionality built in Ubuntu? And is it feasible to change touchpad scrolling speed?

I use MacBook Pro trackpad, and I want to set the speed as smoothly and user-friendly as OS X.

Thanks.

[Update to answer the question by mdoran3844]

```
/dev/input/event0
   bustype : BUS_HOST
   vendor  : 0x0
   product : 0x1
   version : 0
   name    : "Power Button"
   phys        : "LNXPWRBN/button/input0"
   bits ev : EV_SYN EV_KEY

/dev/input/event1
   bustype : BUS_HOST
   vendor  : 0x0
   product : 0x3
   version : 0
   name    : "Sleep Button"
   phys    : "LNXSLPBN/button/input0"
   bits ev : EV_SYN EV_KEY

/dev/input/event2
   bustype : BUS_I8042
   vendor  : 0x1
   product : 0x1
   version : 43907
   name    : "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
   phys    : "isa0060/serio0/input0"
   bits ev : EV_SYN EV_KEY EV_MSC EV_LED EV_REP

/dev/input/event3
   bustype : BUS_I8042
   vendor  : 0x2
   product : 0x6
   version : 0
   name    : "ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse"
   phys    : "isa0060/serio1/input0"
   bits ev : EV_SYN EV_KEY EV_REL
```

Answer (score 12):

I have a MacBook Pro 11.1 running Kubuntu 14.04. Synaptic is installed, but the X11 and Synaptic config files aren't in quite the same location as listed in mdoran3844's answer.

However, based on [this KDE forum post](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=121764#p314459) post here, I ran the following command, which worked on my hardware/software environment:

```bsh
synclient VertScrollDelta=20 HorizScrollDelta=20
```

If that change works but isn't permanent, you may need to place it in something like your `.xinitrc` or another start-up script (or hunt down the config files listed by mdoran3844's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/330478/20626)).

Comment: for "natural mode" scrolling use negative values: `synclient VertScrollDelta=-20 HorizScrollDelta=-20`

Answer (score 5):

This depends greatly on how your touchpad is working. Many touchpad gestures actually don't use any of the Ubuntu gesture or touch events and instead once a gesture is recognized such as two finger scrolling a macro or keycombination is performed.

In your case when the two finger scrolling is recognized then a mouse scroll event is propagated into the event device generic hardware driver, evdev.

You can use the [Synaptics Touch](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad) input driver to configure your most touch pads and touch screens. When using Synaptics, you can alter the scroll speed by changing the VertScrollDelta and HorizScrollDelta located in the config file.

```
sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf
```

And then edit these two lines

```
Option "VertScrollDelta" "10"
Option "HorizScrollDelta" "10"
```

Note: The higher the value the slower and more accurate the scrolling will be. This may seem counter intuitive to the standard mental model of sensitivity.

Comment: You meant Synaptics Touch is pre-installed in Ubuntu? Also, when I run `input list` as explained in the linked post, there is no trackpad detected in my console.  So maybe MacBook Pro's internal trackpad doesn't work in Ubuntu? (I use it in Parallels, virtual environment).

Comment: if `xinput list` doesn't show your touch pad then you won't be able to get any events up into applications unless they are listening for raw events at the `evdev` input layer level.

If you touchpad isn't recognized thats a different issue entirely, but you said it was allowing you to scroll?

Can you run `sudo lsinput` and let me know of the results?

Comment: Thanks. I posted the result in the original post. Maybe `/dev/input/event3` is my touchpad? But it reads mouse, not touchpad - that's why I said `there is no trackpad detected in my console`. I don't use mouse at all for your information, just internal, equipped keyboard and trackpad in MacBook Pro.