# control scrolling speed in webpages in firefox

Tags: firefox, touchpad, scrolling

i recently started using Ubuntu.

i noticed that two finger scrolling in webpages is very fast. much faster than windows. i am using Firefox browser. any idea how to decrease the speed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Open a new tab in Firefox, and enter into the address bar: `about:config`.

There may be a warning about the sensitivity of the advanced settings within, accept the risk and proceed.

There will be a search bar at the top, search for:

```
mousewheel.default.delta_multiplier_y
```

The default value seems to be `100`. Change it to something like `30`, and save with the checkmark on the right.

The updated scroll speed should be experienced immediately.

Mind you, this setting seems to influence both the mouse's scrollwheel and the two-finger scrolling on the touchpad. I don't know how could one configure the two independently from each other.

Answer (score 1):

As @Levente pointed out you should use `mousewheel.default.delta_multiplier_y` to a value like 30, don't forget to do the same for the x value, `mousewheel.default.delta_multiplier_x`.

However, if you want you mouse wheel to control the same you should also change `mousewheel.min_line_scroll_amount` from 5 to 180, althought personally, I found 120 to be more confortable for me.

This bug has been reported already a couple years ago here, so all we can do is wait until they fix it one day.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1610477
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1752862

Comment: I simply set `mousewheel.min_line_scroll_amount` to 2 (default was 5). That and smooth scrolling (enabled via the Firefox settings page) made for a pleasing experience.

Answer (score -1):

Go to settings via the menu (three bars) and search for "scroll". And you will see an option for 'smooth scrolling'.

If you want a custom speed for scrolling, you can use the 'smooth scrolling' firefox Extention.

Comment: i found a "logitech smooth scrolling" extension is it the one you were referring?

Comment: @johnS no. Not that. I can't find the extension I meant in the Mozilla store now. I think it has been removed somehow. Then you have only the first option. Looks like levente's solution works